# Multiple subscriptions causing source stream to fire twice

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-observables

I want to use RxJS to listen to clicks, perform a transaction, and keep track of the transaction status:

```
function performTransaction() {
  const status = {
    '0': 'pending',
    '1': 'success'
  }
  return interval(1000).pipe(take(2), map((i) => status[`${i}`]))
}

const click$ = new Subject<void>()

const claimTxnState$ = click$.pipe(switchMap(() => {
  console.log('performing transaction') // -> runs once which is expected
  return performTransaction()
}))

claimTxnState$.subscribe((v) => {
  console.log('claimTxnState', v);
})

export default function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => click$.next()}>click me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This causes `performing transaction` to be output once, as is expected.

But I want to pipe `claimTxnState$` to more places:

```
const claimIsPending$ = claimTxnState$.pipe(map((claim) => claim === 'pending'))

claimIsPending$.subscribe((v) => {
  console.log('claimIsPending', v);
})
```

This now causes `performing transaction` to be output twice, which I understand because these are cold observables that get recreated on each subscription.   But I don't want this.  I only want my `performTransaction` to get called once.  How can I achieve this?

[Complete example.](https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-snowflake-8nlle2?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer as I was typing the question.  I need to use the `share` operator to convert the observable from `cold` to `hot`.  This has the effect of sharing `claimTxnState$` between all subscribers (i.e. `.pipes(...)`):

```
const claimTxnState$ = click$.pipe(
  switchMap(() => {
    console.log('performing transaction')
    return performTransaction()
  }),
  share() // <- this is the interesting line
)
```

[Sandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-framework-piiymy?file=/src/App.tsx)

[More detail.](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/share)